# Trader Workstation on Ubuntu cannot be connected to via the API

Tags: python, ubuntu, interactive-brokers

I am using ibPy to connect to TWS on a fairly fresh ubuntu machine. I have been successful in logging into the paper trading account and submitting buy and sell orders programatically via the ibPy interface.

However, I am now trying to do more than simply submit orders. Namely, I am trying to obtain position updated from TWS. I am interested in successfully running the following code:

```
from time import sleep
from ib.opt import ibConnection, message

def error_handler(msg):
    print(msg)

def acct_update(msg):
    print(msg)


con = ibConnection(clientId=100)
con.register(acct_update,
         message.updateAccountValue,
         message.updateAccountTime,
         message.updatePortfolio)
con.register(error_handler, "Error")
con.connect()
con.reqAccountUpdates(True, 'DU000000')

sleep(1)
con.disconnect()
```

When executed however I obtain the following error:

```
<error id=-1, errorCode=502, errorMsg=Couldn't connect to TWS.  
Confirm that "Enable ActiveX and Socket Clients" is enabled on 
the TWS "Configure->API" menu.>
```

I have ensured that indeed ActiveX and socket clients are enabled in the TWS preferences, so that is not the issue. It surprises me that I would be able to submit orders successfully but not obtain account updates from TWS. Does anyone know why this could be happening?

Comment: The accounts are different and have their own settings.  Check the real account for the same settings.  Also check the connect from local host setting.  I have had similar problems in mint but it eventually went away, ??

Comment: I had that error and in my case (Java API) the problem was that TWS [was listening](https://www.interactivebrokers.com/en/software/tws/usersguidebook/configuretws/apisettings.htm) on port 7497 while my API calls were on 7496; when I started calling on 7497 the error went away. `It surprises me that I would be able to submit orders successfully but not obtain account updates from TWS.` At least with the Java API, immediately after connection a method gets called (`accountList` or something like that) to which account data is passed, not sure it's what you are looking for though.